# How to reuse a Spring Data JpaRepository interface

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-data-jpa

(Using Java 8)

I have a Spring Data JPA repository interface that I use in my persistence layer. It's in charge of table A.

Here is the code of the interface:

```
package com.bla.bla.persistence;

import com.bla.bla..EntityA;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Transactional
public interface TableAJPARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, Long> {

    @Query("select distinct i.username from EntityA i")
    List<Integer> findDistinctUsernames();

    @Modifying
    @Query("update EntityA i set i.firstName = ?3 where i.lastName = ?1 and i.age < ?2")
    int updateEntityA(Integer age, String firstName, String lastName);

    @Query("select i from EntityA i where i.firstName = ?1 and (i.age =?2 or i.lastName =?3)")
    List<EntityA> findByFirstNameAndAgeOrLastName(String firstName, Integer age, String lastName);

    @Query("select DISTINCT(i) from EntityA i, EntityA1 r  where r.bookId=i.id " +
            "and i.firstName=?1 and r.title=?2 and i.lastName=?3 and i.age!=2 and i.age<=?4 " +
            "order by i.firstName Desc, i.age DESC ")
    List<EntityA> findBySomeFields(String firstName, String title, String lastName, Integer age,  Pageable pageable);
    ...
}
```

Some of the queries join with a helper table A1.

I now have table B which is identical to table A, except for its name. Table B uses table B1 for the joins, which is identical to table A1.

The interface has many methods and I'd hate to duplicate the code.

Id there any way to create an interface that is exactly like `TableAJPARepository` but deals with table B and B1 instead?

Comment: Why do you even have a lot of those methods? Seems like you want to bypass JPA... (and Spring will generate the query for you instead of you needing to specify it).

Comment: Use [SpEL expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions).

Comment: @M.Deinum, these are just examples. Other queries have joins and ordering. The other issue would be changing the join table `A1` to table `B1`...

Comment: @manish, thanks for that link. I probably should have mentioned this in the question, but some of the queries have joins to a secondary table `A1` which has to change to `B1`, to work with table `B`. I'll add it to the question...

Comment: You will need to do something like `select distinct e from #{#entity} e join e.children c where e.firstName = ?1 and c.title = ?2 ...` instead of naming the join classes explicitly. Of course, any strategy to have a common (reusable) base will work only if all entities are polymorphic (i.e. `EntityA` has a `children` collection and so does `EntityB` and so on). The exact types of the polymorphic objects will not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider making a custom repository - note the @NoRepositoryBean annotation -

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.*;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface YourRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {
}
```

The first method shouldnt need @Query since Distinct is a method name option on spring jpa -

```
List<T> findDistinctUsernames();
```

Id need to have a think on the update - but you could likely use generics for this

Comment: This doesn't address the main problem - changing the entity name in the query. And there are lots of them.

Comment: you define a generic NoRepositoryBean - then have two extend this repository for table A and B

Comment: But the table/entity name is a constant in the `@Query`.